# Working with homeomorphism and quotient map

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I am working with a topic of quotient map and homeomorphism. Assume $X = [0, 2\pi]$ and I define a map $f: X \rightarrow S^{1}$ by the function
$$f(t) = e^{it}$$
a) If I assume $\sim$ is the equivalence relation on X, given by
$$\forall x \in X, x \sim x. \text{Also}\, 0 \sim 2\pi, \text{and}\, 2\pi \sim 0.$$
I denote $q: X \rightarrow X/\sim$ be the quotient map. Show that there is a homeomorphism $\bar{f}: X/\sim \rightarrow S^{1}$ which satisfies $\bar{f} \circ q = f.$

I am wondering how to show such a map is a homeomorphism. Do I have to show that it is well-defined and then show that it is bijective to satisfy the definition of a homeomorphism?

b) Now, I want to denote another map g which is the restriction of f to $[0,2\pi]$. Would g be continuous and bijective? I am wondering since g is the restriction of f, it may somewhat have some properties from f, so g can be a homeomorphism as well. But I could be wrong since I cannot find a way to prove or disprove it.

Any tip would be helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the map $\textbf{f}$ in part (b)?

Comment: It is the same map f defined originally.

Comment: Hello Dough, your hint is to prove part a)?

Comment: @DougM how can that statement be sufficient to show that $\bar{f}$ is a homeomorphism. Don't I have to show that (by definition) that the map $\bar{f}$ is bijective, and $\bar{f}, \bar{f^{-1}}$ are continuous? I am sorry I did not catch your hint.

Comment: Ah, I read "homomorphism" an important "e" is missing,

Comment: I see. So I should the follow the definition of a homeomorphism then.

Answer (score 1):

By the universal mapping property of quotient spaces, the fact that $f$ identifies $0$ and $2\pi$ means that your $\overline{f}$ exists and is continuous.  It is also onto because $f$ is.  It is one-to-one because $f$ was EXCEPT at $0$ and $2\pi$, but you glued these points together.  Finally, the quotient is compact because $[0,2\pi]$ is and $S^1$ is Hausdorff, so $\overline{f}$ is a homeo.